# exited on signal 11 xhprof

Tags: php, ubuntu

php5, я поставил расширение `XHprof`, сервер работает под Ubuntu 14.04, но когда я пытаюсь его поюзать, получаю `502 Bad Gateway`. Логи nginx пусты, а в логах php-fpm вот это:

```
[17-Jul-2017 19:20:25] WARNING: [pool www] child 8944 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 16.428915 seconds from start
```

У себя в скрипте я написал:

```
if( extension_loaded( 'xhprof' ) ){
    if( function_exists( 'xhprof_enable' ) ){
        xhprof_enable( XHPROF_FLAGS_CPU + XHPROF_FLAGS_MEMORY );
        echo 'OK!';
    }
}
```

Если я закомментирую строку с xhprof_enable(), вылезет `OK!` и вся остальная часть скрипта отработает штатно. Но расширение `xhprof`, выходит, загружено, и функция `xhprof_enable()`, получается, существует (доступна). В `phpinfo()` тоже `xhprof` присутствует. Почему тогда 502? Не, почему 502 понятно, php-fpm падает, но почему он падает? В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Значит ошибки внутри xhprof приводящие к "приложение выполнило недопустимую операцию". попробовать взять другую версию, если это возможно.

Comment: @Mike пробовал и с нуля переставлять, и кэш PECL чистить, и разные версии ставить, и вручную компилить, и через `apt install php5-xhprof` пробовал, всё одно и то же, та-же ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это известный баг для PHP 5.6 на Ubuntu 14.04. Подробнее на [официальной странице](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67997) расширения.